# Nested JQuery if statements using scroll and screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Attempt to change size of navbar on scroll. Only difference is i need two sets of sizes depending on screen size. Shrink class works guaranteed just trying to adjust function to implement screen size.

Edit:
To clarify, I want to adjust the height of the navbar when someone scrolls down the page. Also need a check to see if the screen size is < or > than 768px since I will be wanting two sets of sizes. Would like the larger of the sets to go from 250px and when scrolled change to 150px. On smaller screens I would like the sizes to toggle between 150px and 70px.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('nav').addClass('shrink');
            $(".navbar").css({
                'height': '150px',
            });
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
            $(".navbar").css({
                'height': '250px',
            });
            else if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
                    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
                    $(".navbar").css({
                        'height': '70px',
                    });
                }
            } else {
                $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
                $(".navbar").css({
                    'height': '150px',
                });
```

Edit 2: Tired something like this with no luck

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(window).scroll(function() {
              if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
                // check the screen size
                if ($(window).width() > 768) {
                  $('nav').addClass('shrink');
                  $(".nav-bar").css("height", "150px");
                } else {
                  $('nav').addClass('shrink');
                  $(".nav-bar").css("height", "80px");
                }
              } else {
                // back to normal when there is less scrolling 
                if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                  $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
                  $(".nav-bar").css("height", "250px");
                } else {
                  $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
                  $(".nav-bar").css("height", "100px");
                }
              });
          });
```

Edit 3: I need something like this...how do I make this syntactically correct?

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {      
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('nav').addClass('shrink');
                $(".navbar").css({
                'height':'150px',
            });
            } else {
                $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
                $(".navbar").css({
                'height':'250px',
            });
        } else {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('nav').addClass('shrink');
                $(".navbar").css({
                'height':'120px',
            });
            } else {
                $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
                $(".navbar").css({
                'height':'140px',
        }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: you have "else if" inside of first "else" of the first if statement. That's is one issue. But what do you want to do? just clearly mention what you expect to do with your code so that people can help you.

Comment: edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understood from your question, you can implement it like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {      
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('nav').addClass('shrink');
            $(".navbar").css({
               'height':'150px',
            });
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
            $(".navbar").css({
                'height':'250px',
            });
        }
    } else {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('nav').addClass('shrink');
            $(".navbar").css({
                'height':'120px',
            });
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
            $(".navbar").css({
                'height':'140px',
            });
         }
     }
 });
```

Check out a working example on [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/gPKeGv)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have a custom class called "shrink" defined already. I need it to be added or removed. Also, in the else statement you only define one value. I need two starting heights for the two different screen sizes.

Comment: Just modified my answer. you can add or remove class as you mentioned in your code in the right place. You needed an if-statement structure to do the resizing which my code does.

Comment: what is the issue now? Check out my working example. It is working just fine.

Comment: check out my edited answer. There was couple of syntax issues. It should work perfectly now.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help